# Is there an open/free Perl module/package repository for Windows?

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, activeperl

So, it seems that the ActivePerl package repository is now [restricted to Business Edition users](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#default_repositories). Is there a repository that maintains Perl packages/modules for Windows that is open/free/unrestricted?

Edit: So far all of the ones I have needed are restricted:
DBI, Data::Dumper, Getopt::Long, XML::LibXML, ...
All return "401 Authorization Required"

Edit 2: I'm running ActivePerl 5.12.2, in case that is relevant.

Comment: [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) and plain-old CPAN

Comment: http://www.cpan.org/ ?

Comment: How can I get cpan packages directly from cpan with ActivePerl?

Comment: I don't know about ActivePerl but with Strawberry Perl you just run `cpan DBI`, etc.

Comment: See the second half of [Installing CPAN Modules on ActivePerl 5.18 and Later](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2016/01/installing-cpan-modules-activeperl-518-and-later)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Tried that. When I run cpan I get:

`It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed.  Trying
to install dmake and the MinGW gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager.
This may take a a few minutes...

Downloading MinGW-5.1.4.1...redirect
Downloading MinGW-5.1.4.1...failed 401 Authorization Required
ppm.bat install failed: 401 Authorization Required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the modules in PPM for ActivePerl is free. Only certain modules are locked to Business Edition (BE).

Comment: So far all of the ones I have needed are restricted:
DBI, Data::Dumper, Getopt::Long, XML::LibXML, ...
All return "401 Authorization Required"

Comment: OK, so I finally figured out that I needed to have the latest version of ActivePerl... which is a hassle because I need IT approval to install any software at work. Grrr.